# access violation reading location when I use cvGetSeqElem

Tags: c, opencv

My question is about access violation reading location when I use cvGetSeqElem.

```
IplImage* debugImLBP = NULL;
IplImage* debugImLBPOut = NULL;
debugImLBP = cvLoadImage("B.png",0);
//detect face :
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );
CvSeq faces;
detect_and_draw_objects( debugImLBP, cascade, 1, &faces );  // on this moment I have faces that are not empty

CvRect face_rect = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( &faces, 0); // here I have access violation
```

[image]
The function detect_and_draw_objects :

```
void detect_and_draw_objects( IplImage* image, CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade, int do_pyramids, CvSeq* facesDetect )
{
IplImage* small_image = image;
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* faces;
int i, scale = 1;
/* if the flag is specified, down-scale the input image to get a
performance boost w/o loosing quality (perhaps) */
if( do_pyramids )
{
    small_image = cvCreateImage( cvSize(image->width/2,image->height/2), IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    cvPyrDown( image, small_image, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );
    scale = 2;
}
/* use the fastest variant */
faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( small_image, cascade, storage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING );/* draw all the rectangles */

for( i = 0; i < faces->total; i++ )
{
// extract the rectanlges only
CvRect face_rect = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i);
cvRectangle( image, cvPoint(face_rect.x*scale,face_rect.y*scale), cvPoint((face_rect.x+face_rect.width)*scale, (face_rect.y+face_rect.height)*scale), CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3 );
}
*facesDetect = *faces;

if( small_image != image )
    cvReleaseImage( &small_image );
cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
}
```

[image]
What I do not understand why during detect_and_draw_objects there is not access violation and why there is in "my main" while faces are not empty.

PS : In my company it is obligation to use opencv 1.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that `cvGetSeqElem` doesn't return a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: I tried to check in the folowwing way : 
if (!cvGetSeqElem( &faces, 0)){
  int kkk;
 }
And it gives access violation

Comment: Perhaps `cvHaarDetectObjects` is returning an invalid pointer, such as `NULL` or a pointer to a variable with automatic storage class (a variable on the stack).

Comment: I verified that no, it correctly gives me all rectangles inside detect_and_draw_objects.

Comment: Since calls to `cvGetSeqElem(face, i)` work within the `detect_and_draw_objects` function, but not after it returns, I suspect the memory for `*faces` lies within the temporary storage allocated and released by `detect_and_draw_objects`, and that `*faces` is no longer valid after the storage has been released.

Comment: After studying the OpenCV source code for a while, my comment above is not completely correct, although the gist of it is correct. `cvCreateMemStorage` creates a container which will hold a list of subsequently allocated memory blocks. The call to `cvReleaseMemStorage` destroys the container and the memory blocks it contains (or moves them to the free blocks list of a parent container). `cvHaarDetectObjects` allocates its resultant sequence using memory blocks in that container. So the return value of `cvHaarDetectObjects` is no longer valid after the storage container has been released.

Comment: I added the screenshot, just the whole path I do not want to demonstate in order to show that faces is not empty.
The last comment may be, it is the reason. I will check

Comment: Nevertheless, after `detect_and_draw_objects` returns, `faces` points to memory that has already been freed. You cannot use it.

Comment: faces are free in the end of function detect_and_draw_objects, but I save faces in facesDetect (given as parameter in function detect_and_draw_objects). In main facesDetect has name faces. May be it is confusing, but if you check screenshot and code, it can be clear

Comment: @Viktoriia That is true, but `CvSeq` contains other blocks allocated from the same storage container, which will have been freed. I.e. `*facesDetect` is a shallow copy of `*faces`, not a deep copy.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Do I should to use clone to have deep copy ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to create the storage container outside of the call to `detect_and_draw_objects` and pass it as a parameter? There would be no need to copy `*faces` in that case.

Comment: ok, thanks to all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`cvCreateMemStorage` creates a container which will hold a list of subsequently allocated memory blocks. The call to `cvReleaseMemStorage` destroys the container and the memory blocks it contains (or moves them to the free blocks list of a parent container). `cvHaarDetectObjects` allocates its resultant sequence using memory blocks in that container. So the return value of `cvHaarDetectObjects` is no longer valid after the storage container has been released.
`CvSeq` contains other blocks allocated from the same storage container, which will have been freed. I.e. `*facesDetect` is a shallow copy of `*faces`, not a deep copy.
                    – Ian Abbott